# split a text into several lines (inside a cell) in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel to generate a summery report for my data. I want each summery to be displayed in a single cell. I used VBA and I got something like this:

[image]

I want to be able to display the data like this:

[image]

All the lines should start with "Increase" or "Decrease". How can I do it in VBA? (I have many cells like the one in this example) how to go over a text inside a specific cell and add a new line after each of these words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to fix the macro so it formats the lines correctly in future then you you need to add in a line feed (I use CrLf myself but Excel, for cells, only cares about the Line Feed) by concatenating the elements with vbLf.

My thanks to @retailcoder for pointing out that vbNewLine == vbCrLf, so you can use whichever makes more sense to you.

so something like Range.Value = "line 1" & vbcrlf & "line 2" & vbcrlf & "line 3" etc:

```
Range.Value = _
    "line 1" & vbcrlf & _
    "line 2" & vbcrlf & _
    "line 3"
```

or, personally, I prefer to construct the text through a loop or using Join():

```
Range.Value = Join(Array( _
    "Line 1", _
    "Line 2", _
    "Line 3"), vbCrLf)
```

For it to actually display on new lines, you need to double check that Word Wrap is on (Excel will set it on automatically but just in case it has been overridden by something else) using `Range.WrapText = True`

However, I realise an interpretation is that you just want to quickly fix what is already on the sheet. If this is the case then just manually do a Find and Replace of the word "Increase" or "Decrease" with `Char(10)Increase` or `Char(10)Decrease` respectively, where Char(10) is what you can get by pressing Alt+Numpad 0010, or by pasting in the value of the result from the formula `=CHAR(10)`. Then remove the first character using a formula.

Comment: yep that would work (assuming com1 etc are the lines you have constructed saying "Increase X%.."). You don't need a vbLf after whatever is your last line though.

Comment: Note that "carriage return" + "line feed" (`vbCrLf`) can also be referred to with the more readable `vbNewLine`.

Comment: Okey thank you, so lets say I use this now: 
Selection = com1 & vbLf & com2 & vbLf & com3 & vbLf com4
if one of the elements doesn't exist (if I use a condition for instance) then I get an empty line/ how can I avoid it?

Comment: To properly do it (there are workarounds with `IIF` in-line if but they wouldn't cover all scenarios and you might end up with a trailing new line) use a loop: `For each line in Array(line1,line2,line3): if line <> "" then text = text & line & vbcrlf: next line: text = left(text,len(text)-1) 'strip off trailing vbcrlf`. Alternatively you could use IIF to remove the need for a loop but that is a lot more typing!

Comment: actually where it says `text = left(text,len(text)-1)` it should say `text = left(text,len(text)-len(vbcrlf))`